# What's the difference between \usepackage{ngerman} and \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

Tags: languages, babel, obsolete

Is there something additional that `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` does that a simple `\usepackage{ngerman}` won't be able to do?

Comment: You won't be able to use two languages, for instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you only want to use one language in your document: Contrary to `babel` with the `ngerman` option, the `ngerman` package will not be detected by [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), and the latter will therefore still use the default (english) headings for bibliographies.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/de.comp.text.tex/ngerman$20versus$20babel/de.comp.text.tex/YGOFEigyxR4/CVQWQG2uxxgJ) thread in de.comp.text.tex, `babel` also activates language-specific shorthands (many of which involve `"`) only at the beginning of the document body, while `ngerman` activates them immediately. The following example (without `\mdqoff`/`\mdqon`) results in an incorrect `\inch` macro with `ngerman`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}

% \mdqoff
\newcommand*{\inch}{"-Zeichen}
% \mdqon

\begin{document}

\inch

\end{document}
```

[image]