# ngerman.sty not found

Tags: packages, german

Whenever I try to compile my `.tex` file, I get the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `ngerman.sty` not found.
>   Type `X` to quit or  to proceed,
>   or enter new name. (Default extension: `sty`)
>   Enter file name:
>   ! Emergency stop.
>   
>   l.3 `\begin`

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\begin{document}
xyz
\end{document}
```

This happens even though the `ngerman.sty` package can be found in the following directories:

- `/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/latex`
- `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex`

I also tried running the `texhash` command.

Comment: Did you run `texhash` as root?

Comment: `ngerman` is absolutely obsolet. You should use `babel` with the language option `ngerman`

Comment: As your document seems to find article.cls: Where is it according to the log-file?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72893/whats-the-difference-between-usepackagengerman-and-usepackagengermanbabe

Comment: Using the package \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} instead of just \usepackage{ngerman} I get the following error: 

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel) the language `ngerman'
(babel) I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.

Comment: @Jurg, use the terminal to install `texlive-lang-german`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where can I see this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/no-hyphenation-patterns-were-loaded-for-the-language/102528).

Answer (score 12):

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>) and run the following commands:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german`

(4.) `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I guess that you don't need (6).

Comment: I think it doesn't do any harm, but I'll put it in brackets as it's not really necessary. :)

Comment: Changed to `(4.)`.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german` is sufficient on Ubuntu 23.10.

Answer (score 2):

The original poster appears to be on Ubuntu (I believe); this answer therefore applies to Debian and Debian derivatives in general, and thus to Ubuntu in particular.

It is probably sufficient nowadays to simply install the `texlive-lang-german` package in the usual way (using `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `apt`, `Synaptic` or whatever you normally use to install packages belonging to your Debian or Debian-derived distribution). Adding a PPA in order to solve this problem is probably not necessary.