# How to change date to different language in a letter

Tags: languages, letters, date

I am using the following template in order to create a letter

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
  Petra Mustermann\\
  Vor dem Berg 1\\
  12345 Musterhausen
}
\opening{Liebe Vereinsvorsitzende,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the date to be in german, but the date in the output is in english, as shown in the following picture.
[image]
On page 179 of the [documentation of the package scrlttr2](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf), the date is correctly printed in german.
I am using Linux and pdflatex.

Comment: It says 11. Juni 2019 for me, when compiling using TeXLive 2019 (also on linux)

Comment: I tried with several releases of TeX Live, always getting “11. Juni 2019”. Do you get error messages or warnings?

Comment: @egreg No, what i did to solve the problem was to follow the answer given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157172/ngerman-sty-not-found

Comment: @egreg The problem is solved by installing `texlive-lang-german` as in your link, however I believe the “symptoms” are different here, where the OP wasn't trying to load `ngerman.sty`. As far as I can tell, the OP here should have seen a warning about missing `ngerman.ldf`, namely `! Package babel Error: Unknown option `ngerman'. Either you misspelled it (babel) or the language definition file ngerman.ldf was not found.`

Comment: @frougon The warning was certainly issued. But `texlive-lang-german` provides all is needed, including the obsolete `ngerman.sty`.

Comment: @egreg I fully agree, but: same solution, different manifestation of the problem IMHO (I can't escape the backquote in my previous message anymore...).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to get the correct date (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157172/ngerman-sty-not-found)).

Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + t) and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to add a PPA for `texlive-lang-german`?

Comment: What is one strage link....

Comment: @daleif Indeed, it's invalid: it is the URL-encoding of the text corresponding to the commands...

Comment: @frougon I think it is not necessary. In order to test it, i removed the repository and texlive-lang-german, did an update and successfully reinstalled texlive-lang-german.

Comment: @peer The problem is, we don't know which packages your `apt-get` command installed or upgraded. This is probably recorded in `/var/log/apt` (I use  `aptitude`, not `apt-get`). You might want to use `apt-show-versions | grep "newer than version in archive"` to see if you still have packages that are not yet in your now-current release...

Comment: @frougon `apt-show-versions | grep "newer than version in archive"` doesn't give any output.

Comment: @peer So, if the date is working now, I think we can conclude that using the PPA wasn't necessary and that the solution is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495265/73317).