# Whats the difference between the ngerman package and the babel-package with ngerman?

Tags: babel, german

i use the package ngerman, which works well and transforms umlaut, i.e. \o" to ö, etc. Many people seem to use the babel package with the option ngerman, however. Whats the difference, which one is preferable?

Kind Regards

Comment: Completely related, in my point of view: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72893/whats-the-difference-between-usepackagengerman-and-usepackagengermanbabe?rq=1

Comment: The difference is that the `ngerman` package is obsolete and `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` is the recommended way.