# Undefined control sequence texttransparent in article - MWE

Tags: compilation-error

I am sorry for spamming you with this silly question, but I am getting an 'Undefined control sequence' error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \texttransparent
                 {0.5}{Hello World}
```

My MWE looks like this:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

Hallo Welt

\texttransparent{0.5}{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

I can confirm, that the the `transparent` package is installed (it is listed when I call `tlmgr list --only-installed`).

What am I doing wrong? I am using TexPad, MacOS

The whole output is:

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 623 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  28 JUL 2021 13:13
**
(Ohne Titel.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (transparent.sty
Package: transparent 2016/05/16 v1.1 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
(ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)

Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.

) (babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
) (ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
(ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
(babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel common definitions
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
(txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 125.
)))
No file "Ohne Titel".aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \texttransparent
                     {0.5}{Hello World}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (Ohne Titel.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
transparent.sty    2016/05/16 v1.1 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
   babel.sty    2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
 ngerman.ldf    2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
 ***********

 )


This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 623 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  28 JUL 2021 13:13
**
(Ohne Titel.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (transparent.sty
Package: transparent 2016/05/16 v1.1 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
(ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)

Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.

) (babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
) (ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
(ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
(babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel common definitions
(switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/01/04 3.16 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
(txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count88
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 125.
))) (Ohne Titel.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \texttransparent
                     {0.5}{Hello World}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (Ohne Titel.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
transparent.sty    2016/05/16 v1.1 Transparency via pdfTeX's color stack (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
   babel.sty    2018/01/04 3.16 The Babel package
 ngerman.ldf    2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
 ***********

 )
```

Comment: Very strange. Would you please add `\listfiles` to the preamble and post the output? Unrelated, but nowadays you should use the `babel` package with the `ngerman` option rather than the `ngerman` package. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72893/82917

Comment: Did an edit. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, there you have it: "_Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode._" You are running `latex` (i.e. with dvi output) rather than `pdflatex`.

Comment: What the ****. Can't remember that I've changed anything...?! Thank you very much, I will try to fix this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...